# Does async really enable callers to await?

Tags: c#, async-await

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx):

> If you specify that a method is an async method by using an Async or async modifier, you enable the following two capabilities... The marked async method can itself be awaited by methods that call it.

But [another page gives this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx):

```
private async Task SumPageSizesAsync()
{
    // To use the HttpClient type in desktop apps, you must include a using directive and add a 
    // reference for the System.Net.Http namespace.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // . . .
    Task<byte[]> getContentsTask = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    byte[] urlContents = await getContentsTask;

    // Equivalently, now that you see how it works, you can write the same thing in a single line.
    //byte[] urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    // . . .
}
```

Here we see it call a function `GetByteArrayAsync` which is [not equipped with the async keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551751.aspx), and yet the caller is able to await on the result.

1. Is MSDN wrong when it says that the async modifier enables callers to await?
2. From the caller's perspective, what's the difference between a function that returns `Task<T>`, and the same function marked as async?

Answer (score 4):

> Is MSDN wrong when it says that the async modifier enables callers to await?

No. It does allow callers to await as it rewrites your method to return a `Task`/`Task<T>`. But it isn't the only way to do so. **Any method that returns an awaitable (e.g. `Task<bool>`, `YieldAwaitable`) enables the callers to await**.

> From the caller's perspective, what's the difference between a function that returns `Task<T>`, and the same function marked as `async`?

If it's implemented correctly, there shouldn't be any difference. The `async` and `await` keywords are a way for the compiler to help you write asynchronous code. But they are not necessary. You can (and you always could have) write asynchronous code without them.

Take `Task.Delay` for example. It creates a task, sets a timer, configures the timer to complete the task after some time and returns the task. It doesn't use async-await and it doesn't need to. But by returning a task it allows the caller to await it.

In fact, a lot of the task-returning methods in the .NET framework don't use async-await internally as they are the "root" asynchronous methods. They return a task but don't have a task to await themselves.

Comment: But the only allowed return types from an async method are Task and void, and `async void` cannot be awaited by callers. So it seems to me the async keyword is not what enables callers to await - what matters is the return type, not the async keyword.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish the async keyword makes your method return a `Task`/`Task<T>`. The task itself is the thing that is awaited. You can return a task without those keywords.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish there are also other awaitables like `YieldAwaitable` that you can await which can't be used in an async method but you can return it directly. You can even create your own awaitables.

Comment: To correct the wording: Methods can never be awaited. Awaitables can.

Comment: It seems like the async modifier doesn't do much at all then.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish the async modifier allows you to use the `await` keyword inside the method that has the modifier, it also allows you to do a `Foo foo; ...; return foo;` when the return type is `Task<Foo>`.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish it allows **you** to write asynchronous code that is as simple as synchronous code while using task-returning API. Implementing that "low level" API however is not that simple. But that's why you mostly don't need to write it yourself.

Comment: After some research I found [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/11/11/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-six-whither-async/) that says that the async modifier exists mainly to avoid backwards compatibility issues. That makes it super-clear to me: async's only role is to be syntactic boilerplate, but we need it for hysterical raisins.

Comment: @ridiculous_fish I wouldn't really say that. It's true that that's why async-await (or technically TAP - Task based Asynchronous Programming) has both the async and await keywords and not just await. But in the actual implementation the async keyword enables using await in a method and makes it return a task that contains the result (or exception) when completed.

Answer (score 3):

Do do not await a function, you await a `Task` or a `Task<T>` that a function returns<sup>1</sup>. In any examples where you see `await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url)` there is a hidden implicit `Task<byte[]>` that gets "passed" between the `client.GetByteArrayAsync(url)` and the `await`.

You question is similar to asking "How does the `+` work when you do

```
int result = 1 + 2;
```

vs when you do

```
int two = 2;
int result = 1 + two;
```

The documentation states it is for adding two numbers together, but I am not adding two numbers in the 2nd example I am adding a number and a variable."

---

<sup>1: It is a little more completed than that, but for 99% of the time just think of it that way.</sup>

Comment: How do I reconcile your answer with MSDN's docs that it is the async modifier that enables callers to await?

Comment: Because if you mark a method `async` you also must change it to return a `Task<T>` instead of a `T` or else the code will not compile, the action of returning a Task is what allows the callers to await, it actually has nothing to do with the async keyword it is just a side effect from the new return type.

Answer (score 2):

From [async/await faq](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/async-await-faq.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> What does the “async” keyword do when applied to a method?
>
> When you mark a method with the “async” keyword, you’re really telling
>   the compiler two things:
>
> 1. You’re telling the compiler that you want to be able to use the “await” keyword **inside the method** (you can use the await keyword if
>      and only if the method or lambda it’s in is marked as async). In doing
>      so, you’re telling the compiler **to compile the method using a state
>      machine**, such that the method will be able to suspend and then resume
>      asynchronously at await points.
> 2. You’re telling the compiler to “lift” the result of the method or any exceptions that may occur into the return type. For a method that
>      returns Task or Task, this means that any returned value or
>      exception that goes unhandled within the method is stored into the
>      result task. For a method that returns void, this means that any
>      exceptions are propagated to the caller’s context via whatever
>      “SynchronizationContext” was current at the time of the method’s
>      initial invocation.

So, think of it as a syntactic sugar over plain old asynchronous .NET model: more compiler checks, less code, and completely indifferent from the caller perspective (caller either awaits the result inside `async` method or uses other TPL primitives, or even blocks).

Actually, if you check the [source code of the GetByteArrayAsync method](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L140), it is simply a wrapper over [GetContentAsync](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L164) method constructing the resulting `Task` with `TaskCompletionSource` and continuation-passing style.

```
private Task<T> GetContentAsync<T>(Uri requestUri, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, T defaultValue,
        Func<HttpContent, Task<T>> readAs)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        GetAsync(requestUri, completionOption).ContinueWithStandard(requestTask =>
        {
            if (HandleRequestFaultsAndCancelation(requestTask, tcs))
            {
                return;
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = requestTask.Result;
            if (response.Content == null)
            {
                tcs.TrySetResult(defaultValue);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                readAs(response.Content).ContinueWithStandard(contentTask =>
                {
                    if (!HttpUtilities.HandleFaultsAndCancelation(contentTask, tcs))
                    {
                        tcs.TrySetResult(contentTask.Result);
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An `async` modifier allows you to use the `await` keyword *within that method*. Any `Task` can be awaited within a method marked `async` -- the `Task` represents an ongoing activity that may or may not already be complete when it is returned to the caller.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell it's *not* being awaited. The `Task` is.

`The marked async method can itself be awaited` - that's for methods. A `Task` doesn't need that in order to be awaitable (which is what you're doing in `await getContentsTask`).

This also answers part 2 - The difference is that the one that returns `Task` and is *not* marked `async` cannot be awaited. Which is what MSDN says in the quoted text.

(I might be wrong, of course.)

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @i3arnon Why? The OP mistakenly thinks that awaiting a Task is like awaiting the method that created it. I'm telling him it's not. (Or perhaps I'm simply wrong. If so - please tell me about what.)

Comment: Not.. that's correct. It's just not an answer to the question. It's just commentary.

Comment: As far as I can tell - the OP's question is all based on one mistake. I'm correcting that mistake. Why is this not an answer? If you, the OP, are reading this - how about stating your opinion. Does this answer your question? (If you downvote because you think I'm _wrong_ please leave a comment explaining that. I would be thankful to you for teaching me something new.)